# String replace not removing substring

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am a bit confused as to why I can't get str.replace to remove part of a string in a column of a Pandas dataframe.

Here is my data:

```
asciiname   population  location
0   Casablanca  3144909 https://www.google.com/maps/?q=33.58831,-7.61138
1   Rabat   1655753 https://www.google.com/maps/?q=34.01325,-6.83255
2   Fes 964891  https://www.google.com/maps/?q=34.03313,-5.00028
3   Sale    903485  https://www.google.com/maps/?q=34.0531,-6.79846
4   Marrakesh   839296  https://www.google.com/maps/?q=31.63416,-7.99994
```

I am trying to remove "https://www.google.com/maps/?q=" and just keep the lat long coordinates.

I am running the following code:

```
cities['location'] = cities['location'].str.replace('https://www.google.com/maps/?q=', '')
```

However this does not seem to modify my data at all.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: what does `cities` refer to in this code? I am guessing you are just modifying the wrong target since "cities" is plural it sounds like the whole data set, not a single row like you want.

Comment: Yes cities is my df, location is a column in my dataframe

Comment: Then I believe you are editing properties of the entire dataframe and not its individual rows. I don't know pandas but if dataframes are some kind of iterable then you want to do `for row in cities: row['location'].str.replace('...', '')`. You may need to do something like `for row in cities.iterrows()` from what I see of how dataframes work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just escape the `?` character with a `\`, it should work.

Basically,

```py
cities["location"] = cities["location"].str.replace("https://www.google.com/maps/\?q=", "")
```

Comment: Ok yes that worked perfectly..... could you please explain why? Thanks

Comment: By default, it considers the first parameter as a `Regex` string. A question mark has a special meaning in Regex, which is `0 or 1`.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not wrong, the first parameter of `pandas.Series.str.replace` is considered a regex by default. Just pass `regex=True` as a parameter for your string to be used as a mere string, not a regex.

Like this:

```
cities['location'] = cities['location'].str.replace('https://www.google.com/maps/?q=', '', regex=False)
```